# Not able to create user profile using django-registration

Tags: django, django-registration

I am using django-registration app. I am trying to create a social networking website. I am a newbie to website development. Here is the error I am getting:

Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: 127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/

Django Version: 1.4.2
Python Version: 2.7.2

```
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'registration_defaults',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'registration',
 'polls')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/registration/views.py" in register
  187.             new_user = backend.register(request, **form.cleaned_data)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/registration/backends/default/__init__.py" in register
  79.                                                                     password, site)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  209.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/registration/models.py" in create_inactive_user
  78.         new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in create_user
  160.         user.save(using=self._db)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  463.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  565.                 created=(not record_exists), raw=raw, using=using)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  172.             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "/Users/dineshsingh/Desktop/django/mysite/users/models.py" in create_user_profile
  20.         UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in create
  137.         return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in create
  377.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  463.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  551.                 result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  203.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1593.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  910.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  40.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  344.             return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /accounts/register/
Exception Value: no such table: users_userprofile
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Ok do one thing, check manually whether you have all the table created on hitting `syncdb` or not.

Comment: I have checked and users_userprofile table is not created. The list of tables created is:   auth_group,
auth_group_permissions,
auth_permission,
auth_user,
auth_user_groups,
auth_user_user_permissions,
django_admin_log,
django_content_type,
django_session,
django_site,
polls_choice,
polls_poll,
registration_registrationprofile,

Comment: No no, there won't be any table named `users_userprofile`. `registration_registrationprofile` is the main table here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was using django-registration-defaults and it screwed up things a bit. I was not doing it in a right manner. However, I followed your devdoodles link and than it was working fine.

Comment: Good to know that it worked for you, Now I am putting it an answer so that if others can have this problem they can refer to the answer. And you can consider to accept the answer as `right`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
According to the Error stack, I think you are doing it in the wrong manner. 
It may be that you are creating an app  named `users` which is not required here.
```

Here is the step by step process how to use `django-registration`.

After installing django-registration we need to add it in the `settings.py` file to make sure that our django engine reads it and loads it.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'registration',     #<--Here I have added
)
```

Now You need to add a few more settings in the `settngs.py` file:

```
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 2
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'webmaster@localhost'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Now update the `urls.py` file to send all the `/accounts/` request to the `django-registration` app.

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    (r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
    ...
)
```

Now you need to create some templates to support your `django-registration`.

```
login.html — user login form
logout.html — shown after a user has logged out
password_change_form.html — password change form
password_change_done.html — shown after successful password change
password_reset_form.html — ask user for email to send password-reset mail to
password_reset_email.html — template for password-reset mail
password_reset_done.html — shown after password-reset email has been sent
password_reset_confirm.html — ask user for new password after reset
password_reset_complete.html — shown after successful password reset
registration_form.html — user registration form
registration_complete.html — shown after a user has registered
activation_email_subject.txt — subject of activation email
activation_email.txt — template for activation email
activate.html — shown after a user has activated his account
```

A basic model that what you need to put in these files can be [@the-django-registration-git-hub-link](https://github.com/yourcelf/django-registration-defaults/tree/master/registration_defaults/templates/registration)

Now I hope you can get it running.

Few more link to check out.
[Link 1](http://devdoodles.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/user-authentication-with-django-registration/)
[Link 2](http://agiliq.com/books/djenofdjango/chapter5.html#reusable-apps)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have right `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` in your `settings.py`?

That seems it should be:

```
    AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'registration.RegistrationProfile'
```